# How to rename both a primary key and a foreign key connected with each other?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, alter-table

I created two tables and want to set a *one_to_many* relation.
I firstly created a *primary key* `tappa_id` on table 'tappa' and then a foreign key `tappa_id` connected to the previous one on table *low_cost_hotels*.

I then changed the name of the table *tappa* to *leg*.

**I want to rename** the primary key in the first table and the foreign key in the second one which refers to it but I always get errors. I wonder whether or not the issue is due to the fact that they're already connected with each other:

[image]

I wrote the following code to drop the primary key in the table *legs*-->

```
ALTER TABLE legs DROP COLUMN tappa_id ;
```

And got this error message (*FrancigenaApp* is the name of the database which contains the tables) ->

```
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './FrancigenaApp/#sql-33c0_26' to './FrancigenaApp/legs' (errno: 150)
```

I wrote the following code to drop the foreign key connected to the previous (*tappa_id*) in the table *low_cost_hotels*:

```
ALTER TABLE low_cost_hotels DROP FOREIGN KEY tappa_id;
```

and got the error:

```
    ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './FrancigenaApp/low_cost_hotels' to
 './FrancigenaApp/#sql2-33c0-27' (errno: 152)
```

I suppose I need to drop the foreign key before renaming the primary key but I can't do that and it doesn't seem to be an error in the SQL syntax...

Comment: Yes, you will need to temporarily drop the foreign key then rename the columns and create a new foreign key. I find that when I need to do this, I will script the database out to a SQL file (including schema and data) then edit the SQL file and recreate the database. This solves the issue and has the added bonus of compacting the new database.

Comment: Use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`. Rename the columns. Then `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, even without disabling foreign key checks:

Initial schema:

```
create table parent (
  parent_id int,
  data text,
  primary key (parent_id)
);

create table child (
  child_id int,
  parent_id int,
  data text,
  primary key (child_id),
  foreign key (parent_id) references parent(parent_id)
);

insert into parent (parent_id, data) values (1, 'data');
insert into child (child_id, parent_id, data) values (1, 1, 'data');
```

Rename `parent_id` to `parent_id_new` in both tables;

```
alter table child change parent_id parent_id_new int;
alter table parent change parent_id parent_id_new int;
```

Check the schema:

```
show create table parent;
show create table child;
```

Result is:

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `parent_id_new` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id_new`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `child_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id_new` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`child_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id_new`),
  CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id_new`) REFERENCES `parent` (`parent_id_new`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qpoigpwkAXCZzNPrt5VD8J/0)

In MySQL 8 you can use `RENAME COLUMN` syntax:

```
alter table child rename column parent_id to parent_id_new;
alter table parent rename column parent_id to parent_id_new;
```